# Optimizing the performance of mass inserts from file SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, optimization

I'm currently working with a friend on developing a game that deals with words primarily, so
I have a word list that I entered into a database. The plan is to have individual databases(as in on everyone's phone) be filled up during the installation. I have done every optimization I found on StackOverflow and Google, but it still takes too long, about almost 2 minutes, which is unacceptable for such a simple game.

The wordlist itself consists of around 350000 words, so we have created a file which contains
the same number of inserts(is this the best way to go?), i.e each word has its own line in a text file with a corresponding insert. This is what I currently have:

```
public int initializeDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {

        int result = 0; //returns querys completed
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Opening a file for reading
        InputStream insertStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open("allWords.txt");
        BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertStream));

        //Iterating through lines
        String query = "INSERT INTO words(word,tezina) VALUES(?,?)";//? entered in code
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(query);
        db.beginTransaction();//otvaram transakciju
        while(insertReader.ready()){
                statement.clearBindings();
                String toExtract = insertReader.readLine();//uzimam upit
                String word = "";
                int tezina = (int)toExtract.charAt(toExtract.length() - 2);//extract word difficulty
                for(int i = toExtract.length() - 4; i > 0; i--){

                    if(toExtract.charAt(i) == '(') break;
                    else word += toExtract.charAt(i);
                }//extract word along with ' ', from back to save time
                String reverseWord = "";
                for(int j = word.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                    reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
                }//reverse it
                statement.bindString(1, word);//bind parameters
                statement.bindLong(2, tezina);
                statement.execute();
                result++;
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();//end of transaction
        insertReader.close();
        return result;//return queries completed

    }
```

350262 inserts, line - by - line, taking about 2 minutes. Any better way of doing all of this?

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: No, I don't currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of the text file is rather inefficient (using `String` instead of `StringBuilder`; constructing the unused `reverseWord`).

However, mobile devices are not fast; you will never be able to parse and insert 350,000 rows without some delay.

You should not construct the database on the device in the first place.
Just ship the complete database file in the assets folder, and [copy it to your data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) after installation.

Comment: I will try this and afterwards mark your answer if successful.

Comment: I have since managed to do all of this and succesfully create a db to be shipped. Thanks!